# changing Strings

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

well guys i have a little problem here, i have 3 containers and an XML with n nodes... i want to put in the containers, any value of the XML, this value cannot be one old value and in the containers shouldn't have the same value... i have this code in as3 but it doesn't work :S

```
package 
{ 
   import flash.display.MovieClip; 
   import flash.display.Sprite; 
   import flash.events.Event; 
   import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
   import flash.text.TextField; 



   public class Pruebas extends Sprite 
   { 

      public var arr:Array = new Array("valor0","valor1","valor2","valor3","valor4","valor5") 


      public var str1:String=arr[0]; 
      public var str2:String=arr[1]; 
      public var str3:String=arr[2]; 




      public var te1:TextField = new TextField(); 
      public var te2 :TextField = new TextField(); 
      public var te3 :TextField = new TextField(); 

      public var btn :MovieClip = new MovieClip(); 




      public function Pruebas() 
      { 
         te1.text = str1;     
         te2.text = str2; 
         te3.text = str3; 

         addChild(te1); 
         addChild(te2); 
         addChild(te3); 

         te2.x = 50;te3.x=100; 

         btn.graphics.beginFill(0xff00ff); 
         btn.graphics.drawCircle(151,150,15); 
         addChild(btn); 

         btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,cambiar); 
      } 


      public function cambiar(e:Event):void{ 
         var minLimit:uint = 0; 
         var maxLimit:uint = arr.length-1; 
         var range:uint = maxLimit - minLimit; 

         var someNum:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;       


         if(str1 == arr[someNum]){ 
            while(str1 == arr[someNum]){ 
               someNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit; 
            } 
            str1 = arr[someNum]; 
         }else{ 
            str1 = arr[someNum]; 
         } 
         someNum= Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;    

         if(str2 == arr[someNum]){ 
            while(str2 == arr[someNum]){ 
               someNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit; 
            } 
            str2 = arr[someNum]; 
         }else{ 
            str2 = arr[someNum]; 
         } 

         someNum= Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;    

         if(str3 == arr[someNum]){ 
            while(str3 == arr[someNum] || str3 ==str1 || str3 == str2){ 
               someNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit; 
            } 
            str3 = arr[someNum]; 
         }else{ 
            str3 = arr[someNum]; 
         } 




         te1.text = str1;     
         te2.text = str2; 
         te3.text = str3; 
      } 


   } 
}
```

---

Eduardo Check this code that this code I did

```
if(imgactual == myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero){
                while(imgactual == myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero){
                    someNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;
                }
                imgactual = myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero
            }else{
                imgactual = myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero
            }
            someNum= Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit; 

            if((imgpostactual == myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero) || (imgpostactual == imgactual) ){
                while(imgpostactual == myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero || imgpostactual == imgactual){
                    someNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;
                }
                imgpostactual = myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero
            }else{
                imgpostactual = myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero
            }

            someNum= Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit; 

            if((imgpreactual == myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero) || (imgpostactual == imgpreactual) || (imgpreactual == imgactual)){
                while((imgpreactual == myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero) || (imgpostactual == imgpreactual) || (imgpreactual == imgactual)){
                    someNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;
                }
                imgpreactual = myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero;
            }else{
                imgpreactual = myXML.internas.item[someNum].@numero;
            }
            trace(imgactual);
            trace(imgpreactual);
            trace(imgpostactual);
```

the bad with this code is that always the loop while takes a long time :S and i think that it doesnt work :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to check if the second choice is the same object as the first, and the third choice is the same object as the first and second, grabbing a different random object if any of them match.

Something like:

```
var index1:int = (int)(Math.random() * arr.length);
var index2:int = index1;
while (index2 == index1) {
    index2 = (int)(Math.random() * arr.length);
}
var index3:int = index1;
while (index3 == index1 || index3 == index2) {
    index3 = (int)(Math.random() * arr.length);
}

str1 = arr[index1];
str2 = arr[index2];
str3 = arr[index3];
```

a `do while` loop is ideal for this...I couldn't remember the syntax offhand, though.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to pick 3 different random numbers between 0 and maxLimit, and then pick the elements of the array at those index positions. One way to do it, giving each index an equal chance, is to create an array with your sub-indexes, which you shuffle, and then pick  the first three elements. Something like this:

```
// Create the array with the indexes
var idxArray:Array = new Array();
for(var i:int = 0; i<=maxLimit; i++) idxArray.push(i);

// Shuffle it
for(var j:int = 0; j<=someNumberBigEnough; j++){
  var idx1:int = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;
  var idx2:int = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;
  // to shuffle, swap elements
  var aux:int = idxArray[idx1];
  idxArray[idx1] = idxArray[idx2];
  idxArray[idx2] = aux;
}

// Pick the first thee
str1 = arr[idxArr[0]]
str2 = arr[idxArr[1]]
str3 = arr[idxArr[2]]
```

where `someNumberBigEnough` could be, for example, equal to `range`

Comment: hmmm ok u shuffle the position of the array is ok... but in the other loop? imagine that changes every 1 minute and each time must have different values in the arrays :S that is my problem each time they change always someone is the equal to other :S

Comment: You could either reshuffle, or take the following 3 elements in the array.

Comment: do you seem any error in my code? syntax or logico i dont know or for u my code work?

Comment: I do: for example, you are checking that str2 is equal to some random element of the array. If it is not (and you get into the else) then you no longer check that it is different than str1. mouseas's solution follows your same idea but is a bit cleaner and should work.